# Creating own script for collapsible accordion using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, accordion

I have a simple snippet of code for an accordion. At the moment you can click on `accordion-control` and it opens each panel 1 by 1. However I want it so when the user clicks on another `accordion-control` button, it closes the panel that is currently displayed and displays the content the user selected

**Code**

```js
$(function() {
  $('.accordion').on('click', '.accordion-control', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.accordion-control').removeClass('active');
    $(this).next('.accordion-panel').addClass('active').not(':animated').slideToggle();
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="accordion no-padding no-margin-bottom">
  <li>
    <button class="accordion-control text-md-left">Accordion button</button>
    <div class="accordion-panel">
      <ul class="no-padding">
        <li>lorem ipsum text</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="accordion-control text-md-left">Accordion button</button>
    <div class="accordion-panel">
      <ul class="no-padding">
        <li>lorem ipsum text</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="accordion-control text-md-left">Accordion button</button>
    <div class="accordion-panel">
      <ul class="no-padding">
        <li>lorem ipsum text</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="accordion-control text-md-left">Accordion button</button>
    <div class="accordion-panel">
      <ul class="no-padding">
        <li>lorem ipsum text</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the below working. Let me know if this is what you wanted. I decided to hide the according at the start as well. If you want to show it at the start, you should be need to add the active class to all the panels as well.

```js
$('.accordion-panel').hide();
$('.accordion-control').click(function() {
    if($(this).next('.accordion-panel').hasClass('active')){
       $('.active').removeClass('active').slideUp();
    }else{
      $('.active').removeClass('active').slideUp();
     $(this).next('.accordion-panel').addClass('active').slideDown();
    }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="accordion no-padding no-margin-bottom">
    <li>
        <button class="accordion-control text-md-left">Accordion button</button>
        <div class="accordion-panel">
            <ul class="no-padding">
                <li>lorem ipsum text</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button class="accordion-control text-md-left">Accordion button</button>
        <div class="accordion-panel">
            <ul class="no-padding">
                <li>lorem ipsum text</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button class="accordion-control text-md-left">Accordion button</button>
        <div class="accordion-panel">
            <ul class="no-padding">
                <li>lorem ipsum text</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button class="accordion-control text-md-left">Accordion button</button>
        <div class="accordion-panel">
            <ul class="no-padding">
                <li>lorem ipsum text</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The only suggestion I'd have for your answer is to do `display:none;` in your CSS, instead of doing the `.hide();`. Much more efficient to do that in CSS. That being said, nice solution. +1

Comment: @Santi - I agree, I think that was part laziness on my side.

Answer (score 1):

I would address this differently, personally.

Why not just shrink all accordions any time one is clicked, and reveal the one that *was* clicked?

Condensed JSFiddle:

```js
$('.accordion').on('click', '.accordion-control', function(e) {

    //Any time you'll be using a selector more than once, set it to a variable
    $ap = $(this).next(".accordion-panel");

    //Restrict closing all accordions
    if (!$ap.hasClass("active")) {

        //Slide all the accordions up
        $(".accordion-panel").slideUp().removeClass("active");

        //Slide the clicked accordion down
        $ap.slideToggle().addClass("active");
    }
});
```

```css
.accordion-panel {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="accordion no-padding no-margin-bottom">
    <li>
        <button class="accordion-control text-md-left">Accordion button</button>
        <div class="accordion-panel">
            <ul class="no-padding">
                <li>lorem ipsum text</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button class="accordion-control text-md-left">Accordion button</button>
        <div class="accordion-panel">
            <ul class="no-padding">
                <li>lorem ipsum text</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button class="accordion-control text-md-left">Accordion button</button>
        <div class="accordion-panel">
            <ul class="no-padding">
                <li>lorem ipsum text</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button class="accordion-control text-md-left">Accordion button</button>
        <div class="accordion-panel">
            <ul class="no-padding">
                <li>lorem ipsum text</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Only thing is you can't close the panel if you try clicking on the same button.

Comment: I specifically coded for that. This could easily be adjusted by removing the `if`.

Comment: Removing the if wont work. It will expand slide the below div up and then back down. But this is a good alternative if you always want one open.